# Cider for emacs Stdin:

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

What combination of keys do I need to press in order to end the input process when I'm in this state?

[image: What it looks like now]

I've input a few lines and hit enter. Now I want it to evaluate the function and show the contents of 'input'.

Comment: Usually a C-g (control-g) interrupts this kind of "states". Doesn't it work for you here?

Comment: I don't think the goal is to interrupt the command, but to signal the end of input --- like when you input CTL-D to signal the end of input in a terminal window.

Comment: I'm using CIDER a lot but have never seen this prompt.  How do you get into this state?

Comment: @Svante, try evaluating `(slurp *in*)` at the REPL prompt --- **and be prepared to restart cider** if you can't figure out how to get out of it without extreme measures :-)

Comment: I'm the author of CIDER. Can you please file a ticket for this? Seems I didn't really think about that particular use case.

Comment: How I love StackOverflow? Let me count the ways...`(range)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I've played with this today and pressing `C-c C-c` in the REPL kills the infinite read loop. While not a proper solution for the bug, it's at least a decent workaround for people affected by this.